# Configure Logback.xml to log to separate files for error logs

Tags: java, log4j, logback

I have been trying to configure logback.xml fie to log the error and debug levels(debug and info)to a separate file and log all levels to console.

But its always logging all levles to all files.

I have the below logback.xml file.

```
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="/var/log/demo" />

    <appender name="FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %X{TransId} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <file>${LOG_FILE}/infoLevel.log</file>
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/archived/infoLevel.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ANALYSER"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %X{TransId} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <file>${LOG_FILE}/Analyser.log</file>
            <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/archived/Analyser.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <encoder>
                    <pattern>%d{ HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %X{TransId} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
            <file>${LOG_FILE}/ExceptionLogs.log</file>I
            <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
            <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                <param name="levelMin" value="ERROR" />
                <param name="levelMax" value="ERROR" />
            </filter>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/archived/ExceptionLogs.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %X{TransId} - %msg%n
                    </Pattern>
            </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="com.demo" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ANALYSER" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" level ="ERROR"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" level ="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
         <appender-ref ref="FILE-ANALYSER" />           
    </root>
```

Basically I am trying to have **FILE-ANALYSER** to have info,debug,error logs and **FILE** to have only info and error and  **FILE-ERROR** to have only error logs.

Any help is appreciated.